How did I create note of phone call time and date on OnePlus 7 Pro
I use a OnePlus 7 Pro. After I made a call to Simon, I closed the Phone app and was left with a 'Notes' page with the text "outgoing call to Simon" with the time and date.
By the way, after I tapped on the tick to confirm it, the note disappeared and I can't find it.
How did I manage to create this note without meaning to? To be honest, I wondered if there might be something uninvited on my phone logging calls.

Does this happen with other outgoing/incoming calls? Also, is the time the exact time you made a call, not an approximation?

It's the only time I have seen it and, yes, it was the exactly the same time as in the call list in the phone app.
